# A Memory Error by Using OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, vector, out-of-memory

Photo is here:

[image]

I want to see this white man in green when I clicked left-mouse and [CTRL] button.

The code looks 8-neighbour point of the clicked point and makes recursive.
The code works correctly in the small matrix. But in this photo, I get a memory error. I want to see the man in green. How can I fix the code correctly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int n=0;
void yap(int i,int j,Mat* res){
ostringstream t;
Mat *rgb=(Mat*) res;
Mat res1;
res1=*rgb;
t<<"fark_binary"<<n<<".jpg";
    imwrite(t.str(),res1);
if(res1.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0]>=200){
    cout<<j<<"\n"<<i;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0]=0;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1]=255;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2]=0;
    cout<<"yapıldı";

}
    if(res1.at<Vec3b>(i-1,j-1)[0]>=200){
    yap(i-1,j-1,&res1);
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i-1,j-1)[0]=0;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i-3,j-3)[1]=255;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i-3,j-3)[2]=0;

    }
    if(res1.at<Vec3b>(i-1,j)[0]>=200){
    yap(i-1,j,&res1);
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i-1,j)[0]=0;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i-1,j)[1]=255;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i-1,j)[2]=0;

    }

    if(res1.at<Vec3b>(i-1,j+1)[0]>=200){
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i-1,j+1)[0]=0;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i-1,j+1)[1]=255;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i-1,j+1)[2]=0;

    }
    if(res1.at<Vec3b>(i,j-1)[0]>=200){
    yap(i,j-1,&res1);
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i,j-1)[0]=0;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i,j-1)[1]=255;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i,j-1)[2]=0;

    }
    if(res1.at<Vec3b>(i,j+1)[0]>=200){
    yap(i,j+1,&res1);
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i,j+1)[0]=0;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i,j+1)[1]=255;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i,j+1)[2]=0;

    }
    if(res1.at<Vec3b>(i+1,j-1)[0]>=200){
    yap(i+1,j-1,&res1);
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i+1,j-1)[0]=0;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i+1,j-1)[1]=255;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i+1,j-1)[2]=0;

    }
    if(res1.at<Vec3b>(i+1,j)[0]>=200){
    yap(i+1,j,&res1);
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i+1,j)[0]=0;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i+1,j)[1]=255;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i+1,j)[2]=0;

    }
    if(res1.at<Vec3b>(i+1,j+1)[0]>=200){
    yap(i+1,j+1,&res1);
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i+1,j+1)[0]=0;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i+1,j+1)[1]=255;
    res1.at<Vec3b>(i+1,j+1)[2]=0;
    }
 }

void mouseTikla(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param) 
{   Vec3b color;  
Mat* rgb = (Mat*) param;

Mat p;

p=*rgb;
if (flags == (CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN+CV_EVENT_FLAG_CTRLKEY)) 
{ 
    yap(y,x,&p);

    cout<<x<<y;
 }

 }

int main(){
Mat res;
res=imread("C:/Users/giray/Desktop/27.jpg");
int i;
int j;

//res1.data[res.channels()*(res.cols*(i)+(j))];

namedWindow("Secim", 1);

setMouseCallback("Secim", mouseTikla, &res);
imshow("Secim", res);

waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You say you "get a memory error", what do you mean by that? What error? Where do you get the error? Have you tried debugging your code to find or locate the error, or to catch he error in action?

Comment: By the way, in the `yap` function I see you modify `res1` a lot. But it's a local variable inside the function. The (early) recursive calls will not see those (later) changes, and the changes will be lost when the function returns and `res1` goes out of scope. And have you checked that you don't go out of bounds with your index arithmetic (`i` and `j` plus/minus one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is so wrong in a thousand ways...

1. Never use recursion if you can do it without it
2. Why did you actually create so many pointers to that single image?
3. Formatting helps, really.
4. Memory reallocation is just insane here.

Here's the better version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <queue>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void yap(int i,int j, Mat* res){
    queue<pair<int, int>> q;


    q.push(pair<int, int>(i, j));
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        pair<int, int> p = q.front();
        q.pop();

        if ((p.first < 0) ||
            (p.second < 0) ||
            (p.first >= res->rows) ||
            (p.second >= res->cols))
            continue;

        if (res->at<Vec3b>(p.first, p.second)[0] > 200)
        {
            res->at<Vec3b>(p.first, p.second) = {0, 255, 0};
            q.push(pair<int,int>(p.first - 1, p.second - 1));
            q.push(pair<int,int>(p.first + 1, p.second + 1));
            q.push(pair<int,int>(p.first - 1, p.second + 1));
            q.push(pair<int,int>(p.first + 1, p.second - 1));
            q.push(pair<int,int>(p.first + 1, p.second));
            q.push(pair<int,int>(p.first - 1, p.second));
            q.push(pair<int,int>(p.first, p.second + 1));
            q.push(pair<int,int>(p.first, p.second - 1));
        }
    }

}

void mouseTikla(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    Mat* rgb = (Mat*) param;

    if (evt == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        yap(y,x,rgb);
        imshow("Secim", *rgb);
    }
}

int main(){
    Mat res;
    res=imread("put_your_path_here");
    namedWindow("Secim", 1);

    setMouseCallback("Secim", mouseTikla, &res);
    imshow("Secim", res);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Heh, sorry, missed out that you were using Ctrl key. Fix it if you'll use my example.

Comment: i want to coordinates what i clicked pixel while i make man in green i wrote code get coordinates but i cant implement your code.My code is below. @Leontyev Georgiy